# Existe alguma propriedade no Maven para acessar o valor de diretório de "resources"?

Tags: java, maven

> Baseada na questão https://stackoverflow.com/q/9216557/4438007

Eu sei que eu posso usar `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` para acessar o meu diretório de arquivos fonte. Se eu quiser acessar o diretório de arquivos de recursos, os *resources*, como faço? O `${project.build.resources.resource.directory}` não deu certo.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada se algo [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216557/referencing-resources-directory-from-project-object-model-variables) te ajuda?

Comment: @StatelessDev de fato, copiei e colei, mas sem entender. Por que é um vetor? Existe a posição 1? O que significaria?

Comment: Na verdade, googlei pra ver se encontrava algo em inglês, achei e coloquei aqui pra te ajudar haha. Se conseguir resolver e postar uma resposta, vou aprender também. ;)

Comment: Você pode usar: `${basedir}/src/main/resources/`. Ou está procurando por uma variável única, que carrega toda esta informação?

Comment: @Dherik eu estava procurando por uma variável que indicasse belamente a posição. Esse é o lugar padrão, mas pode ser sobrescrito por alguém sem coração, daí eu gostaria de pegar esse diretório que sobrescreve o padrão.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Até onde sei, pra esse alguém sem coração sobrescrever o diretório padrão de "resources" ele teria que especificar o diretório no pom.xml com a tag <resources>. Devido ao fato de ser possível especificar vários "resources", a forma de acesso é um array ${project.build.resources[N].directory}. [Aqui na documentação](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) explica sobre isso.

Comment: @TomMelo é sobre isso mesmo que estou falando. Muito obrigado pela referência. Se puder elaborar uma resposta, seria de grande valia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${project.build.resources[N].directory}
```

**N** = Índice do seu recurso(ex: 0,1,2 e etc).

---

Segundo a [documentação](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html), o diretório padrão de recursos(a.k.a resources) é localizado em:

```
src/main/resources
```

O que nos daria a possibilidade de acesso através da expressão:

```
${basedir}/src/main/resources
```

**Porém**, é possível especificar um diretório diferente do padrão para recursos:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
    ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>[seu-diretório]</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Além disso, ainda é possível especificar múltiplos diretórios de recursos:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
    ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/recursos-1</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/recursos-2</directory>
            </resource>
            ...
        </resources>
    ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Portanto, a expressão do diretório de um recurso é:

```
${project.build.resources[N].directory}
```

Onde **N** é o índice do seu recurso. Exemplo:

```
${project.build.resources[0].directory}
${project.build.resources[1].directory}
...
```

Isso pode gerar outra dúvida: Como sei qual diretório será associado ao índice 0, 1, 2 e etc?

Existe o plugin [help:evaluate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) que ajuda a testar as expressões.

Exemplo:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/recursos-1</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/recursos-2</directory>
            </resource>
            ...
        </resources>
    ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Testando(bash):

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.resources[0].directory | grep -v "\["
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.resources[1].directory | grep -v "\["
```

Apesar da documentação do plugin especificar as opções **-q**(quiet) e **-DforceStdout**, não obtive sucesso para exibir apenas o resultado da expressão ${project.build.resources[0].directory}, por essa razão utilizei **grep -v** para filtrar a saída.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Vou deixar a recompensa um tempinho ainda aberta para que tenha mais visibilidade a pergunta e, também, sua resposta